# Проблемы с тестом глубины OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Только начал заниматься с OpenGL и столкнулся с проблемами с тестом глубины.
Использую шейдеры для текстурированного GL_POLYGON и нескольких of GL_LINE_STRIP

```cpp
void Scene::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    /* Enable smooth shading */
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH);

    /* Set the background black */
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    m_texture = new QOpenGLTexture( QImage( ":/Textures/Blocks.jpg" ) );

    QOpenGLShader vShader_body( QOpenGLShader::Vertex );
    vShader_body.compileSourceFile( ":/Shaders/vShader_body.glsl" );

    QOpenGLShader fShader_body( QOpenGLShader::Fragment );
    fShader_body.compileSourceFile( ":/Shaders/fShader_body.glsl" );

    m_program_body.addShader( &vShader_body );
    m_program_body.addShader( &fShader_body );
    m_program_body.link();

    m_vertexAttr_body = m_program_body.attributeLocation( "vertex" );
    m_texCoordAttr_body = m_program_body.attributeLocation( "texCoord" );
    m_matrixUniform_body = m_program_body.uniformLocation( "matrix" );
    m_texUniform_body = m_program_body.uniformLocation( "tex" );

    QOpenGLShader vShader_line( QOpenGLShader::Vertex );
    vShader_line.compileSourceFile( ":/Shaders/vShader_line.glsl" );

    QOpenGLShader fShader_line( QOpenGLShader::Fragment );
    fShader_line.compileSourceFile( ":/Shaders/fShader_line.glsl" );

    m_program_line.addShader( &vShader_line );
    m_program_line.addShader( &fShader_line );
    m_program_line.link();

    m_vertexAttr_line = m_program_line.attributeLocation( "vertex" );
    m_texCoordAttr_line = m_program_line.attributeLocation( "texCoord" );
    m_matrixUniform_line = m_program_line.uniformLocation( "matrix" );
    m_texUniform_line = m_program_line.uniformLocation( "tex" );

    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
}

void Scene::paintGL()
{
    QPainter painter;

    painter.begin( this );
    painter.beginNativePainting();

    glScalef(scale, scale, scale);        
    glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    QMatrix4x4 modelView;
    modelView.perspective( 45.0f, ( GLfloat ) width() / ( GLfloat ) height() , 0.1f, 100.0f );
    modelView.translate( 0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f );
    modelView.scale( scale );

    modelView.rotate( xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    modelView.rotate( yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    modelView.rotate( zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    if ( !m_program_line.bind() )
        return;
    m_program_line.setUniformValue( m_matrixUniform_line, modelView );

    drawLegs();

    m_program_line.release();

    if ( !m_program_body.bind() )
        return;
    m_program_body.setUniformValue( m_matrixUniform_body, modelView );

    drawBody();

    m_program_body.release();

    painter.endNativePainting();
}

void Scene::drawBody()
{
    m_texture->bind();

    m_program_body.setAttributeArray( m_vertexAttr_body, m_body.vertices.data(), 3 );
    m_program_body.setAttributeArray( m_texCoordAttr_body, m_body.texCoords.data(), 2 );
    m_program_body.setUniformValue( m_texUniform_body, 0 );

    m_program_body.enableAttributeArray( m_vertexAttr_body );
    m_program_body.enableAttributeArray( m_texCoordAttr_body );

    glDrawArrays( GL_POLYGON, 0, 6 );

    m_program_body.disableAttributeArray( m_vertexAttr_body );
    m_program_body.disableAttributeArray( m_texCoordAttr_body );
}

void Scene::drawLegs()
{
    Hexapod_legs hexapod;
    Hexapod_legs::_point point[6];

    point[0].x =  0.59f;
    point[0].y =  1.11f;
    point[0].z =  0.80f;

    point[1].x =  0.91f;
    point[1].y =  0.00f;
    point[1].z =  0.80f;

    point[2].x =  0.59f;
    point[2].y = -1.11f;
    point[2].z =  0.80f;

    point[3].x = -0.59;
    point[3].y = -1.11;
    point[3].z =  0.80;

    point[4].x = -0.91;
    point[4].y =  0.00;
    point[4].z =  0.80;

    point[5].x = -0.59;
    point[5].y =  1.11;
    point[5].z =  0.80;

    Hexapod_legs::_speed speed;

    speed.spd_x = 10;
    speed.spd_y = 0;
    speed.spd_r = 0;

    m_texture->bind();

    std::vector<float> legs;

    m_program_body.enableAttributeArray( m_vertexAttr_line );
    m_program_body.enableAttributeArray( m_texCoordAttr_line );

    m_program_body.setUniformValue( m_texUniform_line, 0 );

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
    {
        legs = hexapod.plot_leg(point[i], i, speed, 5, 10);

        m_program_body.setAttributeArray( m_vertexAttr_line, legs.data(), 3);

        glLineWidth(40);
        glDrawArrays( GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 4 );
    }
    m_program_body.disableAttributeArray( m_vertexAttr_line );
    m_program_body.disableAttributeArray( m_texCoordAttr_line );
}
```

Шейдеры элементарные:

```
//fShader_body.glsl
varying highp vec4 texc;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main( void )
{
    highp vec3 color = texture2D( tex, texc.st ).rgb;
    color = color * 0.2 + color * 0.8;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( clamp( color, 0.0, 1.0 ), 1.0 );
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.z);
}
```

```
//fShader_line.glsl
void main( void )
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.345f, 0.468f, 0.976f, 1.0 );
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.z);
}
```

```
//vShader_body.glsl
attribute highp vec4 vertex;
attribute highp vec4 texCoord;
uniform mediump mat4 matrix;
varying highp vec4 texc;

void main( void )
{
    gl_Position = matrix * vertex;
    texc = texCoord;
}
```

```
//vShader_line.glsl
attribute highp vec4 vertex;
uniform mediump mat4 matrix;

void main( void )
{
    gl_Position = matrix * vertex;
}
```

Положения вершин рассчитываются в не приведенном коде, но с ними проблем нет.
При рендеринге я вижу объекты (линии и полигон) в порядке рисования, а не в порядке глубины. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен!

Необходимо было добавить принудительное включение текста глубины при каждом вызове paintGL():

```
...
glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
...
```